# Java Regex number extract with differing formats

Tags: java, regex

I have a String that can display a number in one of a few formats:

```
Name ProductA Price R 3 250
```

Or

```
Name ProductA Price R 500
```

I don't know in which format the price will appear, so I want to look for both.
I know the Regex for the first String would be:

```
\\bPrice\\sR\\s\\b*(\\d\\s\\d+)
```

And for the second it would be:

```
\\bPrice\\sR\\s\\b*(\\d+)
```

But how would Regex look that checks for both and captures the Price number?

Comment: You probably need `\\bPrice\\sR\\s(\\d+(?:\\s\\d+)?)`. See live demo https://regex101.com/r/1q9nRG/1

Comment: you could change the digits part to `((?:\d\s)*\d+)`

Comment: Thanks @Matt.G, that works! Would you mind explaining the (?:\d\s) part, I see it says "Groups regular expressions without remembering the matched text", but I'm not sure what that means!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an optional group for following digits (price in capturing group one):

```
\bPrice\sR\s(\d+(?:\s\d+)?)
```

String literal: `\\bPrice\\sR\\s(\\d+(?:\\s\\d+)?)`

Breakdown:

- `\bPrice\sR\s` Match literal string `Price R`
- `(` Start of capturing group one

  - `\d+` Match a sequence of digits
  - `(?:\s\d+)?` Match a group of digits preceding an space, if exist, non-capturing group
- `)` End of capturing group

Or use a positive lookbehind to have price in group `0`:

```
(?<=\bPrice\sR\s)\d+(?:\s\d+)?
```

String literal: `(?<=\\bPrice\\sR\\s)\\d+(?:\\s\\d+)?`

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/QNRPHS/1)

Comment: Does this still capture the entire price in one group? Or two? Your first example that is.

Comment: It captures entire price in one group. Do you want them in separate groups? Please see breakdown.

Answer (score 3):

Make `\\s\\d` part optional, like this:

```
\\bPrice\\sR(?:\\s(\\d))?\\s(\\d+)
--          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that the optional part group is *non-capturing*, letting you retrieve the relevant portions of the price through capturing groups 1 and 2.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/DWWyOc/1)

Comment: This makes two capturing groups, and I'm afraid if OP needs two.

Comment: Thanks, so does ?: ? make a portion optional? Also, I want it to be capturing (one group). Will I then just use: (?:\\d\\s)*\\d+)?

Comment: @CornelVerster `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group. If you want to capture the entire thing, use this expression: `\\bPrice\\sR\\s((?:\\d\\s)?\\d+)`